# How to index a heap allocated matrix in C?

Tags: c, matrix, indexing, heap-memory

I am making a minesweeper program in C.

I have this as a global variable:

```c
typedef struct box_t
{
  int box_type;
  int num_mines_bordering;
  int is_flagged;
} box_t;

// my global
box_t * gameboard = NULL;
```

Later in the application it is allocated in the heap based on the number of rows and columns:

```c
gameboard = (box_t *)malloc((rows * cols) * sizeof(box_t));
```

All is well, however, they way I index it now seems incorrect and error-prone. I can't simply do  `gameboard[x][y]` because I get compiler errors and what I have now seems incorrect:

```c
#define GET_LOC(ROW, COL) gameboard[(ROW * sizeof(box_t)) + (COL * sizeof(box_t)) * sizeof(box_t)]
// if you call this it would look like: box_t * loc = &GET_LOC(somerow, somecol);
```

Is there a better way to index it?

Comment: Using `sizeof(box_t` is bound to be wrong.  You need `#define GET_LOC(r, ncols, c) (gameboard[(r) * (ncols) + (c)])` or something similar — you multiply the row number `r` by the number of columns in one row `ncols` and add the column number `c`.

Comment: See [**Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Comment: @AndrewHenle Lundin's write-up is great but I am kinda scared of VLAs in production code as they don't gracefully fail when out of stack space.  I don't think you can tell gcc to disallow vla allocation but allow vla pointers in function calls.

Comment: @AllanWind VLAs are not limited to being on the stack.

Comment: Suggest making `gameboard` a `struct` with all the pertinent information, `struct { size_t x, y; struct box_t *box; } gameboard` or `box[]` (FAM).

Comment: @AndrewHenle Sorry, if I am not clear.  What I am getting at is that I would like a gcc feature to disable VLA stack allocations due to possible overflow but allow heap allocation and allow function argument syntax.  AFAIK, the only flag is -Wvla which disallows any VLA use.  Hmm... I should probably just use `-Wvla-larger-than=`.

Comment: Don't define your own types ending in `_t`; these are reserved for the implementation by POSIX, and defining your own is undefined behavior in a POSIX application.

Comment: You could use a pointer to VLA. `box_t  (*gameboard)[cols] = calloc(rows, sizeof *gameboard);`. It **will not** allocate any memory on stack. All memory **will** be heap allocated. The problem is that `gameboard` could not be a global variable because VLA **types** cannot be defined at file scope.

Comment: @AllanWind The key here is _pointer_ to VLA, which in turn can point at any array no matter where it was allocated and no matter if it's a VLA or static sized. Actual stack-allocated VLA should be avoided in a lot of cases and in this case they want heap allocation anyway. Also, pointer to VLA will once again become a mandatory feature in C23. The main advantage of pointer-to-VLA over "mangled" arrays as in your answer is _increased_ type safety, both by the C compiler and through static analysers if such are used.

Comment: @Lundin I understand that.  The issue is that `gcc -Wvla` will generate a waring for either use case, and I would like the pointer/head benefit but still catch a (large) stack allocation.

Comment: @AllanWind I don't really see how someone would declare a large VLA by accident, or why a VLA in that case would be more dangerous than a static array. Either you have `int array[n];` or you have `int array[n];`... the only difference is that for a VLA `n` could be another variable but in case of a local array it has to be an integer constant expression. And either could cause stack overflows just as easily.

Comment: @Lundin I think of a static array as a compile-time thing, it either works or blows up, while a VLA might blow at any time based on run-time input.  Maybe I am just being overly paranoid.

Comment: @AllanWind No that's wrong. A local array with static size is allocated on the stack, in run-time, just as a VLA. Either will blow up in run-time in case it causes stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler knows the type and hence the size of each array entry, so the only special thing is the number of columns `cols`:

```
box_t *gameboard = malloc((rows * cols) * sizeof(*gameboard));
gameboard[row * cols + col] = ...;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Variably Modified Type (VMT) (i.e. a pointer to VLA). The issue is that this *type* cannot be defined at file scope. The simplest solution is using `void*` for a global variable and VMT for a local, properly typed view.

```
void* gameboard_glob = NULL;
int gameboard_rows, gameboard_cols;

void allocate(int rows, int cols) {
  gameboard_rows = rows;
  gameboard_cols = cols;
  gameboard_glob = malloc(sizeof(box_t[rows][cols]);
}

void foo(void) {
  box_t (*gameboard)[gameboard_cols] = gameboard_glob;

  .. do stuff with `gameboard[r][c]`
}
```

Alternatively, one can do allocation and convenient initialization with:

```
box_t (*gameboard)[cols] = calloc(rows, sizeof *gameboard);

... initialize with gameboard[r][c]

gamebard_glob = gameboard;
```

The memory is freed with simple `free(gamebard_glob)`.

Note that this type of VLA **does not** allocate any memory on stack. All the memory is allocated from heap with `malloc`/`calloc`. Moreover, the number of rows can be changed with `realloc`. This solution requires any C99 compliant compiler what includes pretty much any mainstream compiler except infamous MSVC.

Comment: "The issue is that this type cannot be defined at file scope" One cheeky trick that can be used: `typedef struct { size_t rows; size_t cols; gameboard board[]; } box_t;` Now instead of using `board` as a flexible array member, cast it to `gameboard(*)[obj.cols]` whenever it is used. This is a decent compromise between setting size at compile- vs run-time. It can be taken further by making the struct opaque and hide away the casting inside private encapsulation.

Comment: @Lundin, yes.. it can be done this way. Though I would prefer using `struct { size_t rows; size_t cols; box_t (*board)[]; } gameboard_t;`. Let the struct contain a pointer to incomplete array type and pass all instances of `gameboard_t` by value if possible to avoid extra indirection.

Comment: Well if you use a pointer to incomplete array type it is compatible to any array with same item type. That can be both an advantage or a disadvantage, depending on if you are looking for increased type safety or convenient assignments without casts.

Comment: @Lundin, yes.. there is a trade-off. The C standard should provide some way to somehow use  VMTs in the structures. I am aware of multiple complication which it may introduce.